# How to solve this Undefined offset: 0 error?

Tags: php, laravel

In the congress details page the user select the quantity he want for each ticket type then click "Next" and goes to the registration page. In the registration page there is the registration form.

The congresses table has a column "all_participants":

- If all_participants is "0" means that is only necessary collect info about the user that is doing  the registration, which is the authenticated user. So is used the name, surname and email of the auth user to the registration. And in the registration form is only necessary to show the custom questions associated to the selected ticket types once (for the auth user answer) and should be stored using the id of the auth user
- So, if all_participants is "0" and the user selected ticket types in the previous page that
  have 1 or more custom questions associated, in the registartion
  appears that custom question(s). If there are no custom questions associated with any of the ticket types selected by the user, the user dont need to insert any info because is used his auth information (name, surname and email) to the registration.

The issue is that when the user fill the field and click "Go to step 2" it appears "`Undefined offset: 0`".

Do you know how to properly solve this issue?

Error explained with diagram: (in this case there is a custom question   "Whats your phone?" associated to at least one ticket type selected by the user)

[image]

// Registration form

```
<form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        @if (!empty($allParticipants))
            @if($allParticipants == 1)
                <p>Please fill in all fields. Your tickets will be sent to
                    p{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>

                @foreach($selectedTypes as $selectedType)
                    @foreach(range(1,$selectedType['quantity']) as $test)

                        <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="" value="">
                            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ttypes[]" value="{{ $selectedType['id'] }}"/>
                        @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                       @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                       class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                                <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                       value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
                @else
                    <p>Its not necessary aditional info. Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>

                  @if($selectedRtype['questions'] )
                      <p>You only need to answer the cutom questions below.</p>
                @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                               class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                               value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
        @endif

                @endif
            @endif

        <input type="submit" href="#step2"
               id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
```

// storeUSerInfo method of the RegistrationController that is called when "go to step2" button is clicked:

```
public function StoreUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
    $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($allParticipants){
        $rules = [
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];

        foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
            //dd($value);
            // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }

            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->passes()) {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);

            $participants = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
                    'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'ticket_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],

                    'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                ]);
            }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }


    else {

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];


        foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
            //dd($value);
            // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }

            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);


        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',

            ]);

            $participants = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => '',
                    'surname' => '',
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'ticket_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                        // the error undefined offset is here
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);

    }
}
```

**Db structure relevant for the question:**

```
congresses: id, name, all_participants,...
ticekt type table: id, name, etc
registrations: id, congress_id (fk), main_participant_id (main_participant_id is the id of the auth user the user that does the registration)
participants: id registration_id (fk), ticket_type_id (fk), name, surname
questions: id, question, congress_id (fk)
ticket_type_questions pivot table: id, ticket_type_id, question_id, required (required is 1 or 0, 1 means required)
```

Comment: What line number is shown alongside the exception?

Comment: The error message is saying that the `$participants` array has no value with a key of 0. Given how you are creating that array, that would suggest that `count($request->participant_name)` is 0. Have you tried `var_dump($request->participant_name)` to see what's in there?

Comment: With a var dump like " for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                        var_dump($request->participant_name);" it appears "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ticket_type_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `participants` (`name`, `surname`, `registration_id`, `ticket_ype_id`) values (, , 6, ,))"
"

Comment: That definitely looks like your `$request` object doesn't have the values in it that you expect. You need to look into how that is being generaed...

Answer (score 0):

Just searching for the `0`: when accessing a key of an array you have to make sure the key exists.

I see 4 for-loops with an `$i = 0;` declaration that get used to access an array but never checked. Also you might just want to use a foreach loop, but that is up to you.

**checking if key exists**

```
if (isset($request->participant_question_id[$i])) {
    $answer = Answer::create([
        'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
        // the error undefined offset is here
        'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
    ]);
}
```

**foreach approach**

```
foreach ($request->participant_question as $key => $question)
    $answer = Answer::create([
        'question_id' => $question,
        // the error undefined offset is here
        'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the foreach like "foreach ($request->participant_question as $key => $question)
                        $answer = Answer::create([
                            'question_id' => $question,
                            'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                        ]);
                }" still appears "message
:
"Undefined offset: 0".

Comment: Yes I just did the example for `questions`. But than I need to know: 1) where do the `participants` come from, 2) do they really share the same keys with `questions`? If the answer on 2 is *yes* that you can use `$participants[$key]`. And the same for `participant_question`

Comment: The participants come from the registration form, if "all_participants" is 1 is necessary to collect the name and surname of each participant. So that part is in "                                                    @if($allParticipants == 1)..." in the registration form code.

Comment: The questios are other thing, if there are custom questions associated to a ticket type selected by the user in the previous page (congress details page) that questions also appear in the registration form.